# What is the sup of the cardinalities of the chains in $\mathcal P(X)$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> What is the sup of the cardinalities of the chains in $\mathcal P(X)$, where $X$ is a set?

Here *chain* means *totally ordered set*, and $\mathcal P(X)$ is the power set of $X$ (ordered by inclusion).

We can assume that $X$ is infinite, because otherwise the answer is obvious.

We can assume that $X$ is uncountable, because otherwise the answer is given in these posts of [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2328641/660) and [Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2328644/660).

Clearly, the sup $s$ in question satisfies $\operatorname{Card}(X)\le s\le2^{\operatorname{Card}(X)}$. (If $X$ is countable we have $s=2^{\operatorname{Card}(X)}$.)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078115/existence-of-large-chains-provable-in-zfc and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48231/given-a-cardinal-k-whats-the-biggest-dense-linear-order-with-a-dense-subset-of.

Comment: @EricWofsey - Thanks! I see that this is an old and classic problem. Perhaps the question should be closed as a duplicate. - It seems to me that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078130/660) of yours answers my question above (in the sense that it summarizes what's presently known about the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2078130/660) of Eric Wofsey answers the question.

I'm posting this answer as a community wiki, and I'm panning to accept it as soon as possible in order that the question be considered as answered. If you think the question should be closed as a duplicate, please let me know, and kindly tell me what I should do.

Comment: Other related questions: [Uncountable chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/90946/660) and [Are there situations outside of set theory where it would be useful if ICF were true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732285/660).